# For phrase, "For book owners."

Tags: phrase-requests, english-to-japanese

Is it right to say "本の持ち主のために。" or "本の所有者のために。"?

I'm envisaging a situation where someone has done a simplified version of their book on the internet and it says "For book owners, see page 115 for more details".

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: It's like a heading.
"For book owners:
Read page blah blah blah. . ."

Thank you.

Comment: @Dan Is owing the book a special thing, or anybody can? Are they end users who bought it in the store, or having it for sale? Are they owing copies of the book or copyright owners? Do they still have the book or have lost, lent, or something?

Comment: I think it's clear that ために is probably not what you're looking for. Still, I don't understand the context. Most copies of a book go to people who are owning *and* reading the book. And even if not, why address only the book's owners (which may be a public library) and not all its readers?

Comment: @Earthliŋ I'm envisaging a situation where someone has done a simplified version of their book on the internet and it says "For book owners, see page 115 for more details".

Comment: Ah... I think it has the meaning "If you own the book, you can refer to page..." as opposed to a different page number for a online version or some abridged copy.

Answer (score 1):

Your translation is *not* correct. In this caser, we never say 〜のために**. Instead of it, this is correct:

> 本の所有者/持ち主の方(へ)

But in this case, we use **polite** words. So I would say:

> - 本をお持ちの皆様、(詳しくは)115ページをご覧ください

お持ち and ご覧ください is polite form (尊敬語).

Comment: 「お持ち」は「持つ」の謙譲語(humble language)ではなく尊敬語(honorific/respectful language)ではないでしょうか。「持つ」の主語・動作主は話者でなく聞き手ですので。

Comment: そうでした、すぐ書き換えます。

Answer (score 0):

There is still a lack of context to give a proper answer, but you could try something in the lines of:

> 本をお持ちの方は、XXページへ

Comment: 「[本]{ほん}の[持]{も}ち[方]{かた}」 means "The way of holding a book"... Maybe you meant to say 「[本]{ほん}をお[持]{も}ちの[方]{かた}」, right?

Comment: @chocolate Oops sorry. Thanks for spotting my mistake. I forgot the お in front of the 持ち and probably got a wrong auto-correction/suggestion >.<